# Overlaying a SwiftUI View on a UIKit View with "UpdateCoalescingCollectionView"

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

My app primarily uses UIKit, but I'd like to overlay a SwiftUI view on top of one of my view controllers. However, when I do so, I encounter a strange view with white background that seems to be named "UpdateCoalescingCollectionView." I'm not sure what this is or how to get rid of it.

[image]

I've checked my UIHostingController view's background and the SwiftUI view's background, and they are both set to transparent. I've also tried modifying the SwiftUI view's background with Color.clear and setting the backgroundColor property of the UIHostingController to .clear, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Can anyone help me understand what this "UpdateCoalescingCollectionView" background is, and how I can remove it or make it transparent to properly overlay my SwiftUI view on my UIKit view without any interference?

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: If both you set `yourHostingController.view.backgroundColor = .clear` and `YourSwiftUIView().background { Color.clear }` the problem (if with your code and not a bug) must be elsewhere and we can't tell without seeing the problematic code.

Comment: `.background { Color.clear }` is mean-less, multiple `background` modifiers are not going to cancel each other, that's why swiftui view has no background by default. But setting background color to hosting controller should work indeed.